# How can I capitalize every letter after the > character and stop it when the < character is met?

Tags: javascript, regex, masking

I want to essentially implement the functionality given in [Devexpress Simple masked mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1500) in Javascript. For this I have chosen to use the [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin). The only issue is I am not sure how to implement functionalities using the special characters('>' and '<'). I tried reading about using regex and the replace function but they seem a bit confusing for me. :(

Comment: Please ad our tried code and sample input and output

Answer (score 5):

I would use regex,

```js
var s = 'foo>bar ++ buzz<blah';
alert(s.replace(/>[^<]*</g, function(x){return x.toUpperCase()}))
```

or

```
alert(s.replace(/>[\s\S]*?</g, function(x){return x.toUpperCase()}))
```

- `>[^<]*<` matches all the characters that are present inbetween `>` and  `<`.
- this match is passed as first parameter `x` to the anonymous function which returns all Uppercase form of the matched chars.